# Any way I can get vomit out of my pants while at work?

Tags: cleaning

I just vomited on my jeans due to medications. I am at work, so I can't change my pants. Any methods on removing the vomit?

Comment: Get someone to run out for a cheap pair of pants. Launder the soiled pants as usual (perhaps after a soak). Keep the cheap pants at work for a future emergency.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just use wet wipes (aka baby wipes), with enough of those you should be able to remove most of the vomit and retain tolerable smell to the jeans.

However, there is one hack I can suggest, which is related to *how* to use the wipes:

1. Put one wet wipe below the jeans, i.e. shove it from within, so it's right "below" the vomit stain.
2. Keep the wet wipe inside the jeans with one hand, while cleaning the stain itself with the other hand, using another wet wipe.

This way you should also remove at least part of the vomit that soaked into the jeans, not only from the surface.

This is all of course only temporary, should still throw it to laundry asap.

Answer (score 2):

My brother-in-law would cycle to his office where he kept his business suit, and would change out of cycle shorts, etc, when he got there. Once, he found that his suit pants were strangely missing, so he just wore the shirt, tie, and jacket with his cycling shorts and stayed at his desk as much as possible that day. Then a couple of days later the pants were mysteriously returned, laundered. He figured someone in his office must have had an embarrassing accident of some kind.

So my suggestion to you is to beg/borrow/steal (no, don’t steal!) pants from someone who had the foresight to keep an extra set at the office, and next time, be prepared by being the person who has a change of clothes “on file” at the office. You might also keep a bottle of Febreeze or similar in case of odiferous accident.

I keep a full change of clothes, and also a razor, toothbrush, etc, in my office. I haven’t had to use any of it, ever, but I like the feeling of being prepared.